# combining c++ and java projects

Tags: java, c++

I would like suggestions on how to combine two projects. They are both open source, and I want to implement some of the features from one to the other. Do I need to use some sort of "code converter".

Comment: Get some info about JNI.

Comment: -1: you gave us practically no information about the two projects and it seems you have no idea what you're doing at all

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+java+interop

Answer (score 2):

1. Same process, single application:

   1. Most canonical way - JNI
   2. [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna)
   3. Misc code generators
2. Separate processes written entirely in Java and C++ each:

   1. Protobuf
   2. Memory maps/sockets/pipes
   3. Web services.
   4. CORBA :)
   5. Etc.

So on. All depends on how adventurous you feel, on target platforms and your needs (e.g. if you need both C++ and Java to draw UI - multiprocess solution would be hard).

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to use JNI to call C++ code from Java. It's a very broad topic, so you'd be best to start by reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) and any relevant tutorials you can find online.

This way you're not converting beetween languages - you're using a C++ compiler for C++ code and load the resulting library from Java code.